# react: How to structure components

Tags: reactjs, components

I am taking up react, and need some advice on how to structure my component tree.

I want to build a generic List with filters associated with it

I have:

- List component: displays a list of item. Props:

  - Children: prop(a function) used to render each item of the list 
    `(item) => 
    <li className="list-group-item" key={item.id}>
        {item.name}
    </li>`
  - list: array of object
- Filter Component: bunch of input/select used to filter the list

  - filterList: array containing all the field names
  - onChange: function to call when field changes
  - stateValues: values of the fields (state in the above component)
- ListAndFilterContainer: contains the state the filters and passes it to the list

  - list: list of items passed to the list component
  - children: function passed on to the list as children to display the items
  - filterList: list of fields passed to the filter component

Render of the ListAndFilterContainer:

```
`<div>
    <FilterOnList 
      filterList={this.props.filterList} 
      filterState={this.state.filter} 
      onChange={this.handleFilterChange} />
    <ListComponent 
        list={this.props.list} 
        title={this.props.title}
    >
        {this.props.children}
    </ListComponent>
</div>`
```

Now to make it generic I want to be able to modify the markup on how the list is gonna be rendered, and how the input fields of the Filter component are gonna be rendered.

I want to be able to use the logic of a filtered list but I still want to be free on the presentation.

How could I structure it ? The easiest way I guess would be to inherit the List component and alter the render ? For example creating a CarList extends List ?
Same for the Filter component ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts...

- Good idea to use a container component to hold the state. This a pattern that works well for React.
- It sounds like the ListComponent could just have different types of children and might not need specific handling for different list types. In other words, you might have an array of CarItem components and render it as a children of ListComponent, instead of making a separate CarListComponent. It depends on whether you really need different logic for rendering the different lists. Some visual differences, e.g. smaller row heights, can just be accomplished with CSS, so if you pass in a className prop and render it like `<ul className={this.props.className}>` that can handle a lot of customization.
- If you do find you need separate classes for different types of list components (or items, etc) I would avoid use of "extends", mixins, and inheritance in general. This is controversial, perhaps, but IMO, Javascript on its own is too loosely typed to work with inheritance. You lose track of what is happening when things get a little complicated, e.g. "Which class did I get that function from?" If you want to use inheritance, consider typescript. Otherwise, I'd go with functional composition - just import the functions you need from modules.

Comment: Using 'props.className' sounds nice. However I am wondering if I won't end up with too many props to pass down my component tree ? And as for using composition to alter the rendering of the component, the only way to do that is by passing more props

Comment: Why the reluctance to pass props? It's clean, visible, and a key convention of using React. Re functional composition: no, you don't need to pass in functions as props for this. Say you have a CarListComponent that does some car-specific stuff but also some general stuff common to all types of lists. For general stuff, import functions from a separate list utility module you create and use these functions in CarListComponent.

Comment: For the composition solution, if I go for a List utility (without an actual List component) then I lose the generic List-Filter relation which I want to keep using through the component "ListAndFilterContainer".

Comment: I agree that it's preferable to use a single generic component, e.g. ListAndFilterContainer, if that component really doesn't have much change in logic between different types of lists. But if you do find there is logic customization that can't be handled in the list children or via CSS customization, bite the bullet and make separate classes, e.g. CarList, AirplaneList, etc. Don't make the mistake of creating complicated do-everything components that are customized by different props.